# How do I change the geom_text to currency when it is labeling a bar graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, text, label, geom

I have a bar graph and I have labels at the top of each bar to show the amount.

How do I change this to be in currency format?

Here is an example:

```
df <- tribble(~county, ~amount,
              "A", 200000, 
              "B", 1000000, 
              "C", 500000, 
              "D", 250000)

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = county, y = amount)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = label_dollar()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = amount), vjust = -.5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `label_dollar()(..)`:

```r
df <- tribble(~county, ~amount,
              "A", 200000, 
              "B", 1000000, 
              "C", 500000, 
              "D", 250000)

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = county, y = amount)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = label_dollar()) +
  geom_text(aes(label = label_dollar()(amount)), vjust = -.5)
```

[image: ggplot2 barplot]